# WCF REST and JSON - Serialization and empty elements

Tags: wcf, json, null, serialization

I am returning a list of items (user defined class) in a REST service using WCF. I am returning the items as JSON and it is used in some client side javascript (so the 'schema' of the class was derived from what the javascript library required). The class is fairly basic, strings and a bool. The bool is optional, so if it is absent the javascript library uses a default value, and if it is present (true or false) the value is used.

The problem is if I use a bool, the value is defaulted to false when serialized, and if i use a bool?, the member is still sent accross in the JSON and defaulted to null which causes problems with the library (it wont fall back to the default value).

I know I can probably mess around the the javascript library, but I would like to find a way to just not send any members which are null so they dont show up in the serialized JSON at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are all `true`, `false` and `null` valid states for the `bool` variable?

Comment: true, false and absent are valid and produce different results. Although not supported, if the key exists with a null value, it defaults to false.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685045/how-to-not-return-null-when-a-data-member-field-is-not-set-in-the-data-contract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a little bit of packing and unpacking before and after the serialization.  E.g.:

- You could make two different versions
  of the class, one with and one
  without the bool, and convert as
  appropriate before and after
  transmitting. (sends the least amount
  of data, if # of bytes is a greater
  consideration than code complexity)
- You could add another bool that tells
  whether the first bool is supposed to
  be null.